# multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool not terminating correctly in jupyter/ipython

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-multiprocessing

I'm having an issue getting a task to properly timeout when using the multiprocessing module within a Jupyter notebook.

The timeout does return control to the managing thread, but the child process still executes in the background, as can be seen by any verbose statements in the child process.

How do I properly interrupt/stop the child process when running in the interactive notebook?

The entire parent+child process terminates when executing this same code is as follows.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, TimeoutError
import time

def long_process():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('I still finished executing')
    result = 1
    return result

def timeout_wrapper(*args, timeout=0, **kwds):
    with ThreadPool(1) as p:
        res = p.apply_async(long_process, args=args, kwds=kwds)
        try:
            result = res.get(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            result = 0
    return result

timeout_wrapper(timeout=1)
```

Comment: Did you try `p.terminate()` in the `except` clause? What's the point of using a Pool here, btw?

Comment: I suppose, it should be called by `ThreadPool.__exit__`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after some more digging around, it turns out that even executing this script in a .py the background thread wasn't stopping. I still don't know how/if this can be accomplished with a workflow similar to question above (if anyone knows, I'd be happy to learn it), but I do have a workaround that leverages the `Process` and `Queue` from `multiprocessing`.

The following example returns the expected results and the background process is properly terminated (both in .py  in .ipy).

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing.queues import Empty
import time

def long_process(sleep_time=100, queue=None, **kwargs):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print('I still finished executing')
    queue.put(1)
    
def timeout_wrapper(*args, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    q = Queue(1)
    p = Process(target=long_process, args=args, kwargs={'queue': q, **kwargs})
    p.start()
    try:
        result = q.get(timeout=timeout)
    except Empty:
        result = 0
        p.terminate()
    print('Result is {}'.format(result))


timeout_wrapper(sleep_time=1)

timeout_wrapper(sleep_time=10, timeout=1)
```

Comment: But in this case you are using a subprocess, not a thread, so it isn't really the same thing

Comment: if you actually meant to use a thread, you'd use `threading.Thread` instead of `subprocess.Process`